# Keyboard not showing up in EditText after Fragments CustomAnimation

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-edittext, android-animation

I am using custom animations to switch through different fragments

```
 FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
 ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_right,R.anim.shrink_from_bottom);
 this.getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
 this.getFragmentManager().popBackStack();

 A ft_name = new A();
 ft.replace(R.id.llFragmentContainer, ft_name, "A");
 ft.addToBackStack(null);
 ft.commit();
```

How ever after animation when I go to **A** fragment. All the edittext in that Fragment do not respond to clicks. No keyboard shows up, notthing happens

Fragment A.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:fillViewport="true">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:background="@color/grey_light">

        <View
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:background="@color/green"
            />
    </LinearLayout>


      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/grey"
        android:textSize="15dp"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/text_view_one"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/abc"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>     
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

EditText behaves normally when I comment the custom animations. Please assist.